# How to retrieve URL from online server to MS Access

Tags: ms-access, server

I have a lot of pictures that is going to be hosted online on a dedicated server. Is there a way for me to retrieve URL's from these images and attach them to Access fields automatically?

Edit:

I want to add about 1000 pictures taken from a cell phone to a Hostgator server. The cell phone is already connected to a computer which can access all the images taken from the phone. Let's say the product is a book which has field name of **Name**, **Price** and **Image**. I don't know exactly how the automation would work but I was thinking of something like this:

The user inserts the name of the book and the price of the book but in the place of the image the user clicks a button which uploads the image to Hostgator and also retrieves the URL of the image from there and pastes it into the field.

I have limited experience in Access and VBA so I don't know if something like this is possible. Any other alternative to store image online and get the url pasted to the image field will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Answer is a definite 'yes'. However, there is a big discrepancy between the information you have provided and the minimum that is required to give you any sort of reasonable guidance. Would you kindly clarify your problem a bit more clearly? Please provide a 
[(Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to more plainly explain what you are attempting 
to achieve. As it currently stands, your question is a bit too broad to be answered in a helpful / meaningful way.

Comment: I added further details to my question. If there is still some confusion let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no knowledge about Hostgator nor the upload process, but the download part can be resolved as explained in detail in my article with full code and demos:

[Show pictures directly from URLs in Access forms and reports](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/29679/Show-pictures-directly-from-URLs-in-Access-forms-and-reports.html)

Code is too much to post here, but it can also always be found at GitHub:

[VBA.PictureUrl](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.PictureUrl.git)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gustav but I wanted to store URL's not images from the URL in the Access fields.

Comment: Please read again. It doesn't store any image in the database. It reads URLs and displays the pictures.